# Android Studio and Gradle KTS Build Files

Tags: android-studio, gradle-kts

**Background :**

- Android Studio version : 3.5.3
- Gradle wrapper version : 4.8.

> This project uses Gradle KTS build files which are not fully supported. Some functions may be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating Gradle wrapper to **5.5.1** version.